# How to sort array by value float(value) and another array of string(key) in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

This is an example script below, so I can sort one array which contains values in any order and I also want that order should also get affected in another array of strings (keys).
Please ask for clarification if required.
Thanks

```
//@version=4
study("Array sort feature", shorttitle="Ar_Srt", overlay=true)
var price = array.new_float(3, na)
var ticker = array.new_string(3, na)

btcusd = tickerid(prefix = "BITTREX", ticker = "BTCUSD", session = session.regular)
close_btcusd = security(btcusd, timeframe.period, close)
array.set(price, 0, close_btcusd)
array.set(ticker, 0, btcusd)

ethusd = tickerid(prefix = "BITTREX", ticker = "ETHUSD", session = session.regular)
close_ethusd = security(ethusd, timeframe.period, close)
array.set(price, 1, close_ethusd)
array.set(ticker, 1, ethusd)

dogeusd = tickerid(prefix = "BITTREX", ticker = "DOGEUSD", session = session.regular)
close_dogeusd = security(dogeusd, timeframe.period, close)
array.set(price, 2, close_dogeusd)
array.set(ticker, 2, dogeusd)


var label lbl = na
label.delete(lbl)
if barstate.islast
    lbl := label.new(time + 3600000 * timeframe.multiplier, high, tostring(ticker)+" \n"+tostring(price), xloc=xloc.bar_time, style = label.style_label_center, size = size.normal)
// sorted array label
array.sort(price, order.ascending)
var label lbl2 = na
label.delete(lbl2)
if barstate.islast
    lbl2 := label.new(time + 3600000 * timeframe.multiplier, high*0.99, tostring(ticker)+" \n"+tostring(price), xloc=xloc.bar_time, style = label.style_label_center, size = size.normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays of strings cannot currently be sorted. We have a request to the Pine team to add that capability, but no ETA yet.

Comment: Is there any workaround, I can sort the two arrays like a key-value pair? I want to sort array string by the array of values.

Comment: Other than a custom sorting function for your arrays, not for the moment. We have a suggestion in with the Pine team to provide a sort on multiple arrays by mirroring the reordering of a master array, but the feature isn't in the pipeline yet. This would allow a virtual link between arrays, like table columns. We also have a suggestion in to allow sorting on arrays of strings.

When arrays do not require sorting, you can keep indices into a master array to index other arrays indirectly, but that, unfortunately, doesn't apply to your problem.